How to calculate and code confidence intervals for marginal predictions in GLM.jl/Effects.jl?
I am seeking assistance in how to calculate and write the code to produce 95% confidence intervals for the marginal predictions produced by Effects.jl for a fitted logistic regression model (e.g. using GLM.jl, although eventually I would like to scale this up to MixedModels.jl too).
Using the Bangladesh wells dataset as a minimal reproducible example, I can fit the model and produce the mean marginal predictions on the probability scale sufficiently. I am just unsure how to calculate the 95% confidence intervals on the probability scale in Julia?
**My Julia attempt: **
# Load packages required 
using CSV
using DataFrames
using GLM 
using Effects
using Distributions

# Import 'wells' data 
url = "https://github.com/TuringLang/TuringGLM.jl/raw/main/data/wells.csv";
wells = CSV.read(download(url), DataFrame);

# Fit GLM 
m1 = GLM.glm(@formula(switch ~ 1 + dist), wells, Bernoulli(), LogitLink())

# Extract marginal effects 
rng = StableRNG(2024)
design = Dict(:dist => range(0, 100; length=101))
grid = expand_grid(design)
preds = effects!(grid, m1)

# Use inverse link function to get mean expected value on probability scale 
preds = @chain preds begin
    @mutate(
        switch = inv(1 + exp( - switch ))
        )
end

# Plots.jl figure 
Plots.plot(
    xlabel = "Distance", 
    ylabel = "P(switch)"
)
# Add mean expected probability line 
Plots.plot!(
    preds.dist, 
    preds.switch, 
    seriestype = :line
)
#Code to add ribbon (when I can get the 95% CI columns) 
#Plots.plot!(
#    preds.dist, 
#    preds.switch, 
#    ribbon = (
#        preds.switch .- preds.lwr, 
#        preds.upr .- preds.switch
#        )
#)

What I would like to calculate is the columns lwr and upr in the analogous R analysis of the same dataset below, so that I can eventually add the confidence interval ribbons to this plot.

# Load required libraries 
library(magrittr)       
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)

# Import wells data 
wells <- readr::read_csv(
  "https://github.com/TuringLang/TuringGLM.jl/raw/main/data/wells.csv"
)

# Fit GLM
m1 <- glm(
  data = wells,
  family = binomial(link = "logit"),
  switch ~ 1 + dist
)

# Extract marginal effects 
preds <- ggeffects::ggeffect(
  model = m1, 
  terms = c("dist [0:100 by = 1]"),
  interval = "confidence"
  ) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::rename(
    dist = x,
    switch = predicted,
    err = std.error,
    lwr = conf.low,
    upr = conf.high
  )
head(preds)

> head(preds)
  dist    switch        err       lwr       upr
1    0 0.6470185 0.06031022 0.6195771 0.6735236
2    1 0.6455969 0.05954476 0.6184643 0.6718239
3    2 0.6441728 0.05878547 0.6173474 0.6701225
4    3 0.6427461 0.05803260 0.6162263 0.6684194
5    4 0.6413168 0.05728641 0.6151008 0.6667147
6    5 0.6398850 0.05654716 0.6139709 0.6650087



I don't have an answer to your Julia question, sorry. Just wanted to note that I don't think that ggeffects produces "marginal" predictions. I may be mistaken, but I think those are just "conditional" ones. See here for a discussion of the difference in the context of a different R package: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/plot.html

The different terminology in different contexts can be confusing, indeed. One way to think about predictions is 'which question should be answered ', and this also depends on how to deal with the non-focal predictors. See this doc: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/ggeffects.html - the effects package comes closest to the option (or is the same) as margin = "marginalmeans".

tl;dr: Either manually compute the upper and lower bounds of the CI using the "err" column that is created by effects!, or use effects instead of effects! and get them for free.
As the tutorial and API documentation for the Effects package describe, effects! takes a parameter grid and produces a mean marginal effect for each combination of parameters along with the standard error of the estimate. The effects method (no exclamation point) takes a design dictionary and creates the parameter grid for you, along with upper and lower bounds of the CI estimate of the marginal effects. The output from both methods can be transformed into probability space automatically using the invlink keyword argument, but manual computation of the CI must be done in the transformed space anyway, so it doesn't help to pass that argument to effects!.
Here is how it works for your example:
using CSV, DataFrames, GLM, Effects

# Import 'wells' data 
url = "https://github.com/TuringLang/TuringGLM.jl/raw/main/data/wells.csv";
wells = CSV.read(download(url), DataFrame);

# Fit GLM 
m1 = GLM.glm(@formula(switch ~ 1 + dist), wells, Bernoulli(), LogitLink())

# Extract marginal effects
design = Dict(:dist => range(0, 100, 101))

# method 1: using effects! and computing the 95% CI manually
# note that grid is modified in place!
grid = expand_grid(design)
preds1 = effects!(copy(grid), m1)

# preds1 is a DataFrame with dist, switch, and err columns.
# transform switch to probability scale and compute lower and upper 95% CI bounds
# note that err is the standard error: to get the 95% CI, multiply by qnorm(0.975) ≈ 1.959964
transform!(preds1,
    :switch => (s -> GLM.linkinv.(LogitLink(), s)) => :switch,
    [:switch, :err] => ((s, e) -> GLM.linkinv.(LogitLink(), s .- e .* 1.959964)) => :lower,
    [:switch, :err] => ((s, e) -> GLM.linkinv.(LogitLink(), s .+ e .* 1.959964)) => :upper
)

# method 2: using effects
preds2 = effects(design, m1; invlink = AutoInvLink(), level = 0.95)

# preds2 is a DataFrame with dist, switch, err, lower, and upper columns,
# all properly transformed to probability scale already.

This example makes use of GLM.linkinv to perform the inverse of the link function and DataFrames.transform! to transform all columns of interest in-place.
To demonstrate that it produces similar answers to your R example, this is the data plotted using AlgebraOfGraphics as a line and a band:
using AlgebraOfGraphics, CairoMakie

preds1[!, :Method] .= "effects!"
preds2[!, :Method] .= "effects"
preds = vcat(preds1, preds2)

plot = data(preds) * mapping(:dist => "Distance", color = :Method) * (
    mapping(:lower => "P(switch)", :upper) * visual(Band, alpha = 0.2) +
    mapping(:switch => "P(switch)", linestyle = :Method) * visual(Lines, linewidth = 3)
)
draw(plot)


